# Как поменять цвет текста Spinera

Tags: android, kotlin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<Spinner

      android:id="@+id/spiner"
      android:layout_width="300dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="36dp"


      android:entries="@array/name"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
      tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
      />
```